# adding more output neurons to neural network after training?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence, deep-learning

Is there a problem of adding more output neurons after finishing training my neural network .

for example I teach my neural network how to see oranges and apples and say which one is apple and which one is orange. Shades, shape and texture as inputs and orange and apple as outputs so there are 3 inputs and 2 outputs.

what if I trained them and I wanted to add two more outputs lets say banana and stawberey. If I did that does my neural network previous learning fail ? or do I make something wrong here ? or it is safe to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely need to re-train the network from scratch incorporating the old and new data and four classes instead of two. If you try to add new classes to existing network, you are liable to run into what is called [catastrophic forgetting.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catastrophic_interference). However, you may be fine with only re-training the final classifier, or fine-tuning from previously learned weights.

Comment: ok please i have another question that i make me angry not finding and answer for it

Comment: when i give the neural network data about image processing with 3 inputs like shade, shape and texture . and i trained it with 2 outputs apple and orange . when i train it how would it know any other input that is not apple or orange? what i mean is how when i train neural network with data how it knows the other inputs and give an answer and it didnt even got trained on them ?